# how to stop users accessing robots.txt file in the website?

Tags: robots.txt

I need to stop users accessing robots.txt file in my website. I am not sure if i add robots.txt to 301 redirection in htaccess, google may discard the robots.txt, so Please advise me about this.

Comment: **Why** on earth do you want to do that?  If you're trying to hide URLs, that's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Maybe he's got some libelous comments about Yahoo! bot?! [stack overflow's](http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop users accessing your robots.txt directly.  you can use htaccess to block users having specific region or browser version etc..

Comment: I am not expert in htaccess coding, please guide me in this, is below code make sense.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_user_agent} !(googlebot|Msnbot|Slurp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ http://seo.i-connector.com/  [R,NE,L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .txt

Thanks and regards
Krishna